# Require approval before checking-in code to a project (TFS)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

We have a particularly critical project in one of our solutions and would like any check-ins to that project to be approved by another member of the team. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you had a look around? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715017/how-to-force-code-review-before-check-in-in-tfs-2012-rc

Comment: The only solution I could see is to have someone check-in on someone else's behalf, which isn't the same as approving a check-in.

Comment: Which version of TFS?

Comment: @JohnSaunders TFS Online - it's all done through Visual Studio Online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forcing a code review is not possible at the moment but you could switch to a branching model where merges between the branches are only allowed by the senior developers who perform code reviews.

Although a little drastic, you could even switch to using Git instead of TFVC. Git has support for pull requests where you lock down your master branch and then use the pull requests as a review mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no support for this within TFS. What you could do is:

1. ask the developer to seek a TFS Code Review before each checkin.
2. enforce comments on all change sets.
3. ask the senior developer to review the change set comments before you label the release / deploy etc

Or if the project is critical devote more time towards [pairing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_programming).

Comment: That's not necessarily true. There are check-in policies to require a code review prior to a check-in. Of course, with VSO, it's not an option because VSO currently doesn't allow for custom check-in policies.

Comment: My apologies. There is an unsupported version here. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c476b708-77a8-4065-b9d0-919ab688f078