# How to associate reviewed Work Item while check in programmatically in TFS

Tags: c#, tfs

I have created TFS 2012 Serverside event handler for enforcing code review policy.
I am able to create work item for Code review Request and response. But 
After completed review process, when I am going to check in reviewed code unable to see reviewed work item in Related Work item section in Team explorer window in visual studio 2013. below are my code,

```
var workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)projectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
WorkItemType wiType = workItemStore.Projects[0].WorkItemTypes["Code Review Request"];
WorkItem workItem = new WorkItem(wiType);
workItem.Fields["System.AssignedTo"].Value = "XXXXXX"; 
//ev.ChangesetOwner.DisplayName;
workItem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.CodeReview.ContextType"].Value = "Shelveset";
workItem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.CodeReview.Context"].Value = shelveset.Name;
workItem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.CodeReview.ContextOwner"].Value = shelveset.OwnerName;
workItem.Fields["System.AreaPath"].Value = project.Name;
workItem.Fields["System.IterationPath"].Value = project.Name;
workItem.Fields["System.State"].Value = "Requested";
workItem.Fields["System.Reason"].Value = "New";
workItem.Fields["System.Description"].Value = "Code Review Request  ";
workItem.Fields["System.Title"].Value = "Code Review Request " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
var invalidFields = workItem.Validate();
if (workItem.IsValid())
  workItem.Save();
var responseId = workItem.Id;
var type = workItemStore.Projects[0].WorkItemTypes["Code Review Response"]; 
workItem = new WorkItem(type);
workItem.Fields["System.AssignedTo"].Value = "xxxxxxxx"; 
workItem.Fields["System.AreaPath"].Value = project.Name; 
workItem.Fields["System.IterationPath"].Value = project.Name;
workItem.Fields["System.State"].Value = "Requested";
workItem.Fields["System.Reason"].Value = "New";
workItem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReviewedBy"].Value = "xxxxxxxx";
workItem.Fields["System.Title"].Value = "Code Review Response " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
WorkItemLinkTypeEnd linkTypeEnd = workItemStore.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds["Parent"];
workItem.Links.Add(new RelatedLink(linkTypeEnd, responseId));
if (workItem.IsValid())
  workItem.Save();
```

Comment: Did you mean you want to link a work item to a changeset during the check in?

Comment: What's the detailed process you want to implement? How do you associate the Code Review request to the code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you didn't link your work item to the related changest. Following code shows how to do this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

namespace APPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(url));
            WorkItemStore wis = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            VersionControlServer vcs = ttpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            int wid = 82;
            int cid = 332;
            WorkItem wi = wis.GetWorkItem(wid);
            Changeset cs = vcs.GetChangeset(cid);
            ExternalLink el = new ExternalLink(wis.RegisteredLinkTypes["Fixed in Changeset"], cs.ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri);
            wi.Links.Add(el);
            wi.Save();     
        }
    }
}
```

Similar question about  [TFS - VS Extension: Add work item to pending changes via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331871/tfs-vs-extension-add-work-item-to-pending-changes-via-api) and also check this link: [C# Programmatically Checking in code changes with TFS API while associating the changeset to a Work Item](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/72fa2e9e-5cf0-4243-b51d-77d09cc5a732/c-programmatically-checking-in-code-changes-with-tfs-api-while-associating-the-changeset-to-a-work?forum=tfsworkitemtracking)

Comment: I want to enforce code review policy before check in.

Comment: @user3305131To prevent check-in without a review, you can use a check-in policy. Here's a custom check-in policy that requires code review before check-in for your reference:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c476b708-77a8-4065-b9d0-919ab688f078

Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715017/how-to-force-code-review-before-check-in-in-tfs-2012-rc